# Best way to give azure SQL permissions to Power BI?

Tags: sql, azure, deployment, powerbi

I'd like to allow a Power BI report to access a single azure SQL database in such a way that it could allow for cleaner deployment/replication across multiple products. As of now, I manually provide the reports with a read only SQL login, but having to do this each time a new report is created would be sub-optimal.

Is there any way to integrate Power BI with Azure's MSI, or anything of the sort to allow for smoother deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to the Azure SQL database through the PowerBI online service and then publish this as a ['content pack'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-organizational-content-pack-introduction).

Then you can use the [PowerBI Service Connector](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/connecting-to-datasets-in-the-power-bi-service-from-desktop/) to access the dataset without creds.